# magento store data in custom columns

Tags: magento

I added two text columns to sales_flat_quote_item in order to store data and for other reasons When i add product to cart. my problem is that i cant save the data. i tried a lot of examples but without any success.
here i add the coulmns :

```
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote_item'),
    'pack_name',
    array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable' => true,
        'default' => null,
        'comment' => 'pack_name'
    )
);
$installer->endSetup()
```

;

this is the code in my observer where i try to save the data :

```
$quote_item  = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($quote->Id);
$quote_item->setPackName($string);
$quote_item->save();
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to add columns to flat tables like this. The magic methods aren't working because your update to the schema goes against Magento best practices. If you just want a quick fix though, you can do it with raw SQL queries:

```
<?php

$transaction = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

try {
    $transaction->beginTransaction();

    $query_string = "UPDATE sales_flat_quote_item
                     SET pack_name='packname'
                     WHERE id='id'";

    $transaction->query($query_string);

    $transaction->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
}
```

Be careful though, it's not secure. Make sure your data is sanitized.

Comment: Why its not advisable to add columns like this?
and what should i do? Im not looking for a quick solution, I want the correct way of doing it.